# Ejecutar una consulta desde la base de datos y pasarlo a json

Tags: php, sql-server, mssql, sqlsrv

Tengo un archivo PHP que realiza una consulta en una base de datos SQL Server. El problema que estoy teniendo es que al ejecutar la consulta me lanza este error

> PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string
> given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\organigrama\organigrama\inc\colaboradores.php

Ya he intentado de varias formas y no logro solucionarlo, ya he verificado por consola y la consulta se ejecuta pero en el bloque `foreach` está fallando, creo que algo no está bien en el bloque `foreach`. Aquí dejo el código.

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

session_start();

switch ($_GET["listar"]) {
    case 'listar':
        {

            $SQL    = "SELECT COD_FUNC, NOMBRE_Y_APELLIDO AS nombre, CARGO AS cargo, FOTO_TARGET AS img, ANTIGUEDAD AS antiguedad, NRO_CEDULA AS documento, GERENCIA AS gerencia, SUPERIOR_INMEDIATO AS superior, FECHA_INGRESO AS FechaIngreso FROM COLABORADOR_BASICOS";
            $query  = new query();
            $datos  = $query->queryJson($SQL,"");
            $rows   = "";
            $cont   = 0;

                foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
                $nombre_busqueda= strtoupper(strtolower(utf8_encode($value['nombre'])));
                $nombre_busqueda= str_replace('Á', 'A', $nombre_busqueda);
                $nombre_busqueda= str_replace('É', 'E', $nombre_busqueda);
                $nombre_busqueda= str_replace('Í', 'I', $nombre_busqueda);
                $nombre_busqueda= str_replace('Ó', 'O', $nombre_busqueda);
                $nombre_busqueda= str_replace('Ú', 'U', $nombre_busqueda);

                $nombre_cargo   = strtoupper(strtolower(utf8_encode($value['cargo'])));
                $nombre_cargo   = str_replace('Á', 'A', $nombre_cargo);
                $nombre_cargo   = str_replace('É', 'E', $nombre_cargo);
                $nombre_cargo   = str_replace('Í', 'I', $nombre_cargo);
                $nombre_cargo   = str_replace('Ó', 'O', $nombre_cargo);
                $nombre_cargo   = str_replace('Ú', 'U', $nombre_cargo);

                $nombre_busqueda = $nombre_busqueda.' | '.$nombre_cargo;

                $rows[] = Array("codigo"=>$value['COD_FUNC'], "nombre"=>utf8_encode($value['nombre']), "cargo"=>utf8_encode(ucwords(strtolower($value['cargo']))), "img"=>utf8_encode($value['img']), "antiguedad"=>utf8_encode($value['antiguedad']), "nomDocumento"=>utf8_encode($value['documento']), "nomGerencia"=>utf8_encode($value['gerencia']), "nomSuperior"=>utf8_encode($value['superior']), "nomFechaIngreso"=>utf8_encode($value['fechaIngreso']), "nombre_busqueda"=>$nombre_busqueda);
            }

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($rows);
        }

        break;

    case 'datoscolaborador':
        {
            $SQL    = "SELECT CARGO AS cargo, FOTO_TARGET AS img, ANTIGUEDAD AS antiguedad, NOMBRE_Y_APELLIDO AS nombre, NRO_CEDULA AS documento, GERENCIA AS gerencia, SUPERIOR_INMEDIATO AS superior, FECHA_INGRESO AS FechaIngreso FROM COLABORADOR_BASICOS WHERE COD_FUNC = ".$_GET['idcolaborador'];
            $query  = new query();
            $datos  = $query->queryJson($SQL,"");
            $rows   = "";
            $cont   = 0;

            foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
                $rows[] = Array("nombre"=>utf8_encode($value['nombre']), "img"=>utf8_encode($value['img']), "cargo"=>utf8_encode(ucwords(strtolower($value['cargo']))), "antiguedad"=>utf8_encode($value['antiguedad']), "nomDocumento"=>utf8_encode($value['documento']), "nomGerencia"=>utf8_encode($value['gerencia']), "nomSuperior"=>utf8_encode($value['superior']), "nomFechaIngreso"=>utf8_encode($value['fechaIngreso']));
            }

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($rows);
        }

        break;
}
?>
```

Esta es la conexión a la base de datos SQL Server

```
<?php
  class conexion {
    public function conectar($base = "") {
      $serverName     = "DESKTOP-93FQ7SJ\SQLEXPRESS";
      $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"BDPRUEBA", "UID"=>"aldo", "PWD"=>"1234", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
      $conn           = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

      if($conn) {
        return $conn;
      } else {
        echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `queryJson` en esta llamada: `$datos  = $query->queryJson($SQL,"");`? Cuando algo falle, depura la/s variable/s implicada/s. En este caso, haz un `var_dump($datos);` y dinos qué muestra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la conexión se está haciendo de forma correcta (y espero que esos no sean los credenciales de la BD en producción), es casi seguro que el problema está en la línea

```
$query->queryJson($SQL,"");
```

Para extraer los datos de una consulta sqlsrv ver [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php).

```
// ...
$SQL = "SELECT COD_FUNC, NOMBRE_Y_APELLIDO AS nombre, ...";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row); // Test
    // [*] Aqui haces lo que quieras con la fila.
}
// ...
```

---

- EDIT - Acabo de observar que al principio hay una variable:

```
$rows   = "";
```

Y luego dentro del `foreach` está esto:

```
$rows[] = Array("codigo"=>$value['COD_FUNC'], ...);
```

Obviamente te va a marcar un error. No se puede agregar un array de esa manera dentro de una cadena. Tienes que definir inicialmente así:

```
$rows   = array();
```